# How to sort by three-characters weekday in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MYSQL Table with column with three-characters weekdays like

> Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu..

Now I want to ORDER my **SELECT query** by these weekdays (not alphabetically!). When I do it with the following line, it's doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Day, '%a')
```

Can you give me a working query?

Comment: have you tried order by Day ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY FIELD(`day`, 'Mon', 'tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like (you have not provided more information about the table structure, but anyway):

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS day, date, description
FROM table
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(date);
```

So you must have column in your table `date`, which is full date in order the sorting to work.
It will produce something like:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| day      | date       | description                         |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| Sunday   | 1809-02-12 | Lincoln's birthday                  |
| Sunday   | 1776-07-14 | Bastille Day                        |
| Monday   | 1215-06-15 | Signing of the Magna Carta          |
| Tuesday  | 1944-06-06 | D-Day at Normandy Beaches           |
| Thursday | 1989-11-09 | Opening of the Berlin Wall          |
| Friday   | 1732-02-22 | George Washington's birthday        |
| Friday   | 1958-01-31 | Explorer 1 launch date              |
| Friday   | 1957-10-04 | Sputnik launch date                 |
| Saturday | 1919-06-28 | Signing of the Treaty of Versailles |
| Saturday | 1789-07-04 | US Independence Day                 |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```